# Is it possible to have fermions in Schwarzschild spacetime?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes, differential-geometry

To my understanding Geroch proved that on 4-dimensional non-compact manifold a necessary and sufficient condition for a manifold to have a notion of spinors is to be parallelizabe .[1](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9S-hzg6-moYC&pg=PA365&lpg=PA365&dq=geroch+spin+parallelizable&source=bl&ots=FHLJAGhEU8&sig=KA3LtoMKSgsAnKy7rkuARab2BEY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rAUnVJT8A9HnapWvgdAP&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=geroch%20spin%20parallelizable&f=false)  (General Relativity, Robert M. Wald, University of Chicago Press, 2010, pg 366 )

Also spinors are  a common way to describe fermion fields in quantum field theory.

How is this problem solved when one wants to study this kind of fields in non-parallelizable manifolds such as Schwarzschild for example?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: A quick google search gave this interesting preprint "Twisted spinors on black holes" [arXiv:gr-qc/9905038](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9905038), and "Spinor fields near black hole singularities" [*Class. Quant. Grav.* **12** no 3 (1995) 841](http://iopscience.iop.org/0264-9381/12/3/020)

Comment: And, lo!, you can have fermionic quantum field theory on curved spacetime, set in a black hole setting; see Syed Alwi B. Ahmad's doctoral thesis [Fermion Quantum Field Theory In Black-hole Spacetimes](http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-3621112139711101/unrestricted/SAHMAD.PDF). It seems that you may have to consider spacetime as $\mathbb{R}^{4}-(\mathbb{R}\times D)$ where you just "cut out" the event horizon (and its interior), and construct your spinor field on the rest of spacetime...